# Setting layout legend style in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, legend

I have tried to set the legend style but all methods I had tried were error, there is one example I tried to change the font style of legend:

```
legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend.setTitle("Legend")
legend.style().setFont(QFont("Microsoft JhengHei",14,1,False))

layerTree = QgsLayerTree()
layerTree.addLayer(layer)
legend.model().setRootGroup(layerTree)
basicSettings = QgsLegendBasicSettings()
basicSettings.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10))
legend.model().setBasicSettings(basicSettings)
```

And then it showed the error as below:

```
TypeError: QgsLayoutItemLegend.style(): not enough arguments
```

I also read the QGIS document of the rules of code, however I cannot understand the format such as the example shown below:

```
 setStyleFont(...)
       setStyleFont(self, component: QgsLegendStyle.Style, font: QFont)
       Sets the style ``font`` for a legend ``component``.
```

Would anyone elaborate its meaning and provide an example, so that I can solve the similar problems after that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must specify which part of the legend you want the text style to be applied to. For example, `QgsLegendStyle.Title` applies the style to the title.

```
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName("LAYOUT_NAME")

legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
legend.setTitle("Legend")

### USE THIS STRUCTURE
style = QgsLegendStyle()  # make new style
style.setFont(QFont("Microsoft JhengHei",30,1,False))
# style.set...(...)
legend.setStyle(QgsLegendStyle.Title, style) # set style to the legend
###

layout.addLayoutItem(legend)
```

[Other components of legend](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendStyle.html#acae0c6c735f4cb36f30fc53df74bd84e)